# Real Analysis texts: Royden versus Stein & Shakarchi. Which is better? (and other suggestions welcome)

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

I am taking an introductory "graduate" analysis class and am comparing Analysis books that cover measure theory.

I have had an "advanced calculus" class that covered the standard topics. I am having difficulty deciding what I want to buy.

I am wondering how Royden's book compares to Stein and Shakarchi's. Which is better for a beginner? Which takes a more standard approach? Which is more motivated?

Also other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I recommend Real Analysis for Graduate Students by Bass. It's available for [free](http://homepages.uconn.edu/~rib02005/real.html) on his site. I have a copy of Stein's book; I got it because it has tons of interesting exercises, but I haven't looked at anything else, so I can't help much there.

Comment: I don't know which is better, as I have only read from Royden. However, Royden is free online [here](http://libgen.org/book/index.php?md5=DCFA1EB6CC3CDE23478B973B04DEC8E5). Also, I very much like this book as it covers earlier topics that one would have covered in an advanced calculus course in the first few chapters.

Comment: Look at Lang's "Real and Functional Analysis".

Comment: @Michael Believe or not, you're just going to be confused by different books, start a book, whatever! and try to go further.That's the best advice!

Comment: For measure theory, Royden's book is the best beginner book I've ever seen. But Stein and Shakarchi cover some not so standard stuff that are nice to see at least one time in your life...

Comment: Bass's book is incredibly dry.

Comment: @Michael, perhaps you're right. I got it to prepare for comps, so I was looking for a book that had the definitions, examples, important theorems related to them and tons of problems. I don't think you'll find a single diagram in the book. I've worked through the first 19 chapters, sans the one on differentiation, and it's my goto book on measure theory.